# Plotting multiple x axis profiles from a csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, graph

I am planning to plot vertical profile of multiple parameters on x axis, for example, salinity, temperature, density, against pressure as y axis, in the same graph. This is the kind of plot i am hoping to get : [image: which is used to observe barrier layer thickness in water bodies]

Here is a sample from my data :

```
ï..IntD.Date. IntT.Time. Salinity..psu. SIGMA.Kg.m3. Pressure.dbar.
1  21-April-2019 5:31:55 PM        30.2502      20.2241         0.7160
2  21-April-2019 5:32:00 PM        31.0254      20.8081         0.8409
3  21-April-2019 5:32:05 PM        31.2654      20.9930         1.0551
4  21-April-2019 5:32:10 PM        31.2953      21.0176         1.2694
  Temp..0C. Vbatt.volt.
1   23.4054       12.29
2   23.4148       12.30
3   23.4060       12.29
4   23.4024       12.33
```

I already used these codes:

```
data <- read.csv('file location')
vert_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Pressure.dbar., y = Temp..0C.)) + geom_line(color = '#088DA5', size = 0.75) + labs(size = 18) + ggtitle("temp vs pressure") + theme_grey() + coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse()
```

Which generated this plot :

[image] as you can see, i was able to bring a single profile where the scale of y axis wasn't in reverse order whereas I'd prefer pressure value (0, 5, 10....) starting from the top left corner. Unlike the plot i made where pressure value begins in bottom left corner.

I'd be grateful if someone helped me to get figure where i will be able to plot multiple vertical profile in same graph where y axis is pressure and is in reverse order, as shown in that barrier layer thickness picture.

Answer (score 0):

Add as many geom_line() as required and call aes in each geom_line(). For breaks of 5, add scale_x_continuous and call sequence of breaks in it.

```
vert_plot <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Pressure.dbar., y = Temp..0C.), color = 'blue', size = 0.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Pressure.dbar., y = Salinity..psu.), color = 'red', size = 0.75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Pressure.dbar., y = SIGMA.Kg.m3.), color = 'green', size = 0.75) + 
  labs(size = 18) + ggtitle("Dummy Title") + xlab("Pressure") + ylab("Dummy Label") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits = c(40, 0), breaks = seq(40, 0, -5)) +
  theme_grey() + coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

**Alternate method:**

Instead of going through all these, you can melt the data frame keeping the variable names as groups.

```
library(reshape2)

newdf <- melt(df, id.vars = c("IntD.Date.", "IntT.Time.", "Pressure.dbar."), 
              variable.name = "group")

vert_plot <- ggplot(newdf, aes(x = Pressure.dbar., y = value, color = group)) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.75) + 
  labs(size = 18) + ggtitle("Dummy Title") + 
  xlab("Pressure") + ylab("Dummy Label") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits = c(40, 0), breaks = seq(40, 0, -5)) +
  theme_grey() + coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'd also like to how to reverse y axis, in you figure pressure values start from bottom left corner, i'd like to start them from top left corner. I hope it makes sense. Additionally, is it possible to add another axis label to the plot? as you can see, although you have plotted 3 parameters, only temperature's one is visible.

Comment: Updated my answer and added alternate way of plotting.

Comment: Thank you again for going through the matter. Your alternate method solves most of the problems. However, could you tell me how to put additional labels for x axis ? in the figure, only temperature labels are shows, is it possible that i could maybe show labels of salinity or temperature as well ? like in this figure :  https://imgur.com/z0n5jMI